# Redirect and reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

I am using this `javascript` code for a redirection:

```
window.location.href = '/zona-privada?message='+data;
```

I am working with `php` as a backend, after the redirect, my `php` it is not getting the message parameter. But if I reload the page after it has been redirected it works fine.
Should I do the redirect in a different way? Or what I am doing wrong?

This redirection I am doing it in the `javascript` of an `ajax` request.
Thank you very much

Ajax code:

```
$.post(
  "/url"
).done(
  function(data){
    window.location.href = '/home?message='+data;
  }
);
```

my php (using Zend1)

```
if($this->_params['message']) {
   //code goes here
}
```

Comment: If you have entered correct "?message=something" 
$_GET['message'] will return the message.. 
If you have some Rewrite Rules working they may not pass the query string check that..

Comment: You should look at the post redirect get pattern. It's a best practice when developing your pages. Also it restricts resubmit. It may be of help to your application.

Comment: Yes, can you please post the ajax request you are making as well as the php code you are using to get the paramater?

Comment: The data from your ajax response most likely is not a string :) You can't just pass it as a string..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the value of your variable .Try encodeURIComponent(data) before appending it to the window.location.href

Comment: Try this: 
$.post(
  "/url"
).done(
  function(data){
    window.location.href = '/home?message='+encodeURIComponent(data) ;
return false;
  }
);